# Bootstraps toggle button does not open on click or touch on mobile button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create a navigation bar in bootstrap

everything works fine except one. when ever I resize the browser to width of mobile and click on the toggle button the dropdown menu does not open.

Please help me. All I wanted is "when ever i click on the stacked toggel button i want the drop down to open".

I have also made changes to class as well as ids in data-toggle attribute of the button.

I have included jquery, bootstrap js and bootstrap css. I have displayed the entire code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sellr Buyr</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="keywords" content="keywords1, change later">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->
        <!-- stylesheets and js paths must be updated later -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_sources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_sources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="_sources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
           <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container"><!--fluid container-->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-header"><!--nav-header-->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage">$ SellrBuyr</a>
                    </div><!--/nav-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"><!--main-nav-collapse-->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">LOGIN<i class="caret"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">REGISTER<i class="caret"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="btn-danger"><a href="#">PUBLISH YOUR AD FOR FREE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div><!--/main-nav-collapse-->
                </div><!--/fluid container-->
            </nav>
        </header>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to include jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Updated :**

Are you sure that you linked bootstrap js file properly ?

Remove bootstrap js from  ,Try by adding them before `</body>` and after jQuery library. Below is the correct code (Hope :) )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sellr Buyr</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="keywords" content="keywords1, change later">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->
        <!-- stylesheets and js paths must be updated later -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_sources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="_sources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
           <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container"><!--fluid container-->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-header"><!--nav-header-->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage">$ SellrBuyr</a>
                    </div><!--/nav-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"><!--main-nav-collapse-->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">LOGIN<i class="caret"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">REGISTER<i class="caret"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="btn-danger"><a href="#">PUBLISH YOUR AD FOR FREE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div><!--/main-nav-collapse-->
                </div><!--/fluid container-->
            </nav>
        </header>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="_sources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope. still doesnt work. I am missing something else.

Comment: please make it as solved so that other users will know if they have similar issue